# UNION ALL and NOT IN

Tags: mysql, union

I would like to select all rows from the module_idx and module_idx_pool tables that do not have the same listid column in both tables.

If the listid is in both tables I would like to only select the row from the module_idx table.

```
SELECT * FROM module_idx    
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM module_idx_pool WHERE listid NOT IN ( SELECT listid FROM module_idx )
```

This statement is only returning the rows from module_idx and no others.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `module_idx` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`umodule` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
`accid` int(10) DEFAULT '0',
`images` text,
`address` varchar(60) DEFAULT '',
`city` varchar(30) DEFAULT '',
`county` varchar(30) DEFAULT '',
`state` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
`zip` varchar(12) DEFAULT '',
`price` varchar(20) DEFAULT '',
`listid` varchar(25) DEFAULT '',
`details` text,
`latlng` varchar(30) DEFAULT '',
`baths` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
`bedrooms` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
`sqft` int(6) DEFAULT '0',
`acres` int(6) DEFAULT '0',
`proptype` varchar(30) DEFAULT '',
`detailsurl` varchar(40) DEFAULT '',
`content` text,
`status` varchar(20) DEFAULT 'active',
`type` varchar(10) DEFAULT 'feat',
`subdivision` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
`extra` text,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1501 ;
```

The table structure for module_idx_pool is the same as above

Comment: Can’t reproduce: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dcf2e/1

Comment: Coalesce all your NULLs to non-null domain values in the query. All comparisons to NULL fail, and so all *not equals* and *not in* expressions misbehave for NULLs due to loss of the Excluded Middle in tertiary logic.

Comment: @CBroe: I don't see any NULL values in your SqlFiddle - no wonder **your** example works!

Comment: @PieterGeerkens: Well I didn’t see any NULL values mentioned in the _question_ …

Comment: @CBroe . . . That doesn't mean the `NULL` values aren't there.  Clearly if the OP knew to look for `NULL` values in the subquery, then s/he would probably not be asking the question.

Comment: @Well, OP should have shown an _example_ that illustrates the problem then.

Comment: Pieter, "Coalesce all your NULLs to non-null domain values" the listid can never be null. the complete table can not have null values?

Comment: Your DDL above clearly has *list_id* as a null-able field. That seem to be the problem with your query.

Comment: yes listid is null-able but the code will never allow it to have a null value regardless to what else happens. it turns out that phpmyadmin was returning different results then the server. so my original query works well in my application with the required additional parameters added to the query. It also seems to substantially faster then anything else I found. thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is probably because of `NULL` values.  You can fix this is in two ways:

```
SELECT * FROM module_idx    
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM module_idx_pool
WHERE listid NOT IN (SELECT listid FROM module_idx WHERE listid is not null)
```

Or, the bestter way is to use `not exists`:

```
SELECT * FROM module_idx    
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM module_idx_pool ip 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM module_idx i WHERE i.listid = ip.listid);
```

`NOT IN` returns `NULL` whenever the subquery has a `NULL` value.  This makes sense from the perspective of handling `NULL` values -- because you do not know if a given value is in the list.  However, it is a bit counter-intuitive.  `NOT EXITS` has the more intuitive behavior of ignoring `NULL` values.

Comment: the listid will never be null

Comment: @user3319749 . . . I would check that it is never `NULL`.  A `NULL` value would perfectly fit the symptoms that you describe.

Comment: yes i have been trying in phpmyadmin and all of the above solutions are selecting the same rows from the module_idx table

Comment: well gordon i would love to give you a vote up for your solutions but i do not have enough points. it turns out that phpmyadmin is returning different results then my server. my original query seems to work fine outside of phpmyadmin??? your second solution is what i will be building on for my application. thank you for your time.

Comment: @user3319749 . . . That can happen when they two systems are connected to different databases -- or worse, to different servers with the same database name.

Comment: yes... this is the dev environment in whm and it is currently sharing an ip with the planned live environment. I will put them on different dedicated ips. should be ok?